# Getting correctly from php array to knockout.js observableArray

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, knockout.js

I have searched everywhere but I am simply not able to get this right.
I am basically trying to get a php array to bind (correctly) using knockout observablearray. 
I am pretty sure it has to do with the json-representation of the data and the following adressing of it - but I can't get it right, so any help greatly appreciated!

The code is simply trying to list some users from my database.

HTML:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: user">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: username"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: fullName"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var userArray = <?php echo json_encode($users) ?>;

function userViewModel() {
    this.user = ko.observableArray(userArray);
}

ko.applyBindings(new userViewModel());
```

and my $users php array looks like this (using php var_dump):

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(User)[3]
      private 'id' => string '14' (length=2)
      private 'username' => string 'Testbruger' (length=10)
      private 'fullName' => null
      private 'description' => null
      private 'extraInfo' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => null
          1 => null
          2 => null
  1 => 
    object(User)[4]
      private 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      private 'username' => string 'Ray' (length=4)
      private 'fullName' => string 'Raydioh' (length=4)
      private 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'extraInfo' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
          1 => string '' (length=0)
          2 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    object(User)[5]
      private 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      private 'username' => string 'povl erik' (length=9)
      private 'fullName' => null
      private 'description' => null
      private 'extraInfo' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => null
          1 => null
          2 => null
```

Comment: Those fields in the `User` object are all `private`, how do you expect them to be included in your JSON output?

Comment: Yes, I did notice that - however, the array in php is in no way 'private' or declared as so (I even don't know how to do that).
But do you think this is the source of the error?

Comment: Show your `User` class then

Comment: ok, haim, now I got it working!
Your suggestion regarding the "private" part got me looking in that direction and I found the solution here: [show non public members](http://jondavidjohn.com/show-non-public-members-with-json_encode/)
If you give me an answer, I will reward that...